# Update song/track info from iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, ipod

I have an app that implements the MediaPlayer framework. I can read the state, stop, play, skip, reverse, etc.

How can I update the BPM, or the comments, etc...

I have tried a direct assignment on `MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute` and I get the error:

> Read-only variable is not assignable

I currently have a `UITextField` for collecting user input, and a `UIButton` to save the data.

What methods can be implemented to save/push the data in the `UITextField` to the tracks MetaData.

Any leads would be great!

Comment: Are you wanting to do this programmatically? Either way your question is way too broad and vague to get any response from this site.

Comment: updated for more clarity (i hope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible without jail breaking. An app cannot write to the media library.

Comment: so sad. I can see not changing  many things, but stuff like comments, bpm, etc are not crucial... thanks